# AttributeError at / 'Context' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, django, facebook

I am trying to use django-allauth for facebook login. However, when I have logged in facebook, the user.username still is null. Then, I try to follow the code in django-allauth document, but it keeps throwing the error.

```
AttributeError at /
'Context' object has no attribute 'request'
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
    Django Version: 1.10.6
    Exception Type: AttributeError
    Exception Value:    
    'Context' object has no attribute 'request'
    Exception Location: C:\Users\prairie5270\django\lib\site-packages\allauth\compat.py in template_context_value, line 25
    Python Executable:  C:\Users\prairie5270\django\Scripts\python.exe
    Python Version: 3.6.0
    Python Path:    
    ['C:\\Users\\prairie5270\\Desktop\\website',
     'C:\\Users\\prairie5270\\django\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
     'C:\\Users\\prairie5270\\django\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\prairie5270\\django\\lib',
     'C:\\Users\\prairie5270\\django\\Scripts',
     'c:\\users\\prairie5270\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\Lib',
     'c:\\users\\prairie5270\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\prairie5270\\django',
     'C:\\Users\\prairie5270\\django\\lib\\site-packages']
```

The according code below:

```
14      {% load socialaccount %}
15      {% providers_media_js %}
16      <a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}">Facebook Connect</a>
17  
18      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
19      
20      <a href="/accounts/logout">
21          <button class="btn btn-default">Logout</button>
22      </a>
23      {% else %}
24      <a href="/accounts/login">
25          <button class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
```

Thank you very much in advance! I am happy for any help

Comment: what is your django-allauth configurations ( settings or other code) ?
attach that also ( urls.py may be ? )